# Erro na personalização do cadastro de usuário padrão Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel, relacionamento, request

**Erro após cadastrar e redirecionar**

**PS: ele faz o cadastro normalmente, e consigo acessar normalmente, mas da esse erro sempre!**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EU FIZ UMA MODIFICAÇÃO APENAS NO CADASTRO DE USUÁRIO, FIZ A PARAMETRIZAÇÃO DA MINHA RELAÇÃO MANY TO MANY QUE TAMBÉM FUNCIONA**

```
 public function register(Request $request)
{

    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered(
        $user = $this->create($request->all())->companies()->attach($request->company_id)


    ));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

**O ERRO ESTA NESTE TRECHO DO CÓDIGO  $this->guard()->login($user); **
**ACREDITO QUE O ->attach($request->company_id) esta fazendo o usuário dar um retorno diferente que o $this->guard()->login($user); precisa**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `attach` esta retornando `null` para a variavel `user`.

Na sua função `login` o parametro esperado deve implementar a interface `Authenticable` que é comum na classe `User`, para resolver isso crie uma variavel com o usuario e faça o `attach` sem utilizar os métodos encadeados, veja:

```
$user = $this->create($request->all());
$user->companies()->attach($request->company_id);

...

$this->guard()->login($user);
```

Comment: **Não consigo trabalhar nesta forma que você me passou pois estou dentro da função**

'event(new Registered(
            $user = $this->create($request->all())->roles()->attach(12)
            


        )); 

' @rfl

Comment: @GabrielAlves fala o `register` do usuario fora do `event` e passe apenas o retorno para a classe `Registered`.

Answer (score 0):

**DEU CERTO MT OBRIGADO**

```
$user = $this->create($request->all());
    $user->roles()->attach(12);
    $user->companies()->attach($request->company_id);

    event(new Registered($user));
```

**Uma dúvida!! Estou usando Laravel Defender mas a função $user->attachRole() Da erro de Objeto**

Comment: Gabriel, com relação ao erro no `attachRole` por favor abra outro tópico com sua duvida, pode ser que alguem tenha esse mesmo problema e se sua pergunta estiver em outro topico ficara mais facil pra todo mundo achar